# App Engine: Are the headers like X-AppEngine-Country always non-null?

Tags: google-app-engine, http-headers

I want to use the headers `X-AppEngine-Country` and `X-AppEngine-Region` but i've heard that they're not always populated with non-null values in every request?

Is that true, or can i rely on them to always have values?

I cannot find documentation that says one way or the other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [Request headers](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/how-requests-are-handled#Python_Request_headers):

> X-AppEngine-Country
>
> Country from which the request originated, as an ISO 3166-1 alpha-2 country code. App Engine determines this code from the
>   client's IP address. Note that the country information is not derived
>   from the WHOIS database; it's possible that an IP address with country
>   information in the WHOIS database will not have country information in
>   the X-AppEngine-Country header. Your application should handle the
>   special country code ZZ (unknown country).
>
> X-AppEngine-Region
>
> Name of region from which the request originated. This value only makes sense in the context of the country in X-AppEngine-Country. For
>   example, if the country is "US" and the region is "ca", that "ca"
>   means "California", not Canada. The complete list of valid region
>   values is found in the [ISO-3166-2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-2) standard.